# Responsive table: 2 column table with l+r images...shrink it?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a two column structure. The left holds the left side of one image, and the right holds the right side of the same image. I do this so that a user can click on the left to be directed one place, and the right to be directed another place.

Here's what it looks like:

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: Georgia, Times, serif}
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
    table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
                body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0;}    
                body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
        }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
                body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0;}    
                body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
        }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
    <td class="center" style="padding:0px 0 0 0px">
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="deviceWidth">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px" align="center">
                        <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0"><a href="blah"><img width="290" src="blah" alt="" border="0" style="width: 290px" class="deviceWidth" /></a></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>                        
            </table>                                       
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="deviceWidth">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px" align="center">
                    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0"><a href="blah2"><img width="290" src="blah2" alt="" border="0" style="width: 290px" class="deviceWidth" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>                        
        </table>                                        
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The issue is...I want to make it responsive. But instead of stacking one table on top of the other, I want them to shrink side-by-side so that the image is preserved. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/54c5W/

I'd like the images to remain side-by-side when I shrink the screen, not stack on top of each other.

Comment: Is there some reason you're using all that table markup? Tables with single cells are rarely a good idea.

Comment: yeah, its going to be a mailchimp email template...and i've had better luck doing it like this.

Comment: Ah. In that case, please explain what isn't working. A fiddle might help. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: When I shrink the screen, the left and right images stack one on top of the other. I'd like them to remain side-by-side. http://jsfiddle.net/54c5W/